# Getting GCC error when compiling from source - BYOL Build GCC natively pass 2

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors

[image: error_screencap]

I am reaching the second pass of Compiling GCC natively in the BYOL project. I keep running into problems and would like to understand them. I have tried changing the $PATH order and starting the project over (this is try number 7).

Here is the config.log error line:

```
conftest.c:10:10: fatal error: isl/schedule.h: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Other than creating and building as the `lfs` user, what other instructions from the book did you skip?

Comment: none that I know of. byol - build your own linux - is my lfs user @rfmodulator

Comment: You're also not building in $LFS/sources. LFS is a very reliable and stable build if you follow the instructions. Don't change things (like `$PATH`) unless you're instructed to do so. My guess is that you've skipped some of the environment setup and host requirements. Did you delete the source directory after GCC Pass 1? The best advice I can give is if you decide to start over at page one, don't deviate from the instructions in the book. No matter how trivial it may seem to name your user `byol` instead of `lfs`, at the very least it raises all sorts of red flags when you ask for help.

Comment: I get the importance of  details and for clarity's sake, im following the naming conventions set by "Build your own linux" from linux academy. I know they are slightly different than the book, but as far as i can tell, everything else goes by the book.  I did delete the source directory and i feel I have been diligent with the env. I have restarted so many times and always have errors at gcc pass 2, which is why asked. Maybe I should specify building GCC w/o LFS? I feel following a course isnt too crazy. all alterations are at suggestions to this GCC problem, otherwise I am going by the book.

Comment: Then this isn't a Linux From Scratch question. Anyway, you can probably solve your problem by doing the same thing with the `isl` package as you did with `mpfr`, `gmp` and `mpc` (i.e. `tar -xf ../isl-X.XX.tar.xz && mv -v isl-X.XX isl`).

Comment: yes I have tried exactly that already, per gnu prerequisites ( https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html )  . Ill try asking about building GCC then, I thought maybe someone could have had this problem with this project before though, and could offer advice or insight.

Comment: It's also possible to build and install isl before gcc, which is what I do. It will install its headers in `/usr/include/isl/`. Its the same procedure as most other packages: `./configure --prefix=$WHATEVER --disable-static && make && make install`.